# OIDC client + Identity Server 4, setting max_age silent token reniew not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have an angular 10 application with OIDC JS client as open id connect. On browser or tab close I need to redirect the user back to the login page.

By setting `max_age` to the UserManager the functionality is working fine, however, silent token reniew is not working while using the application and it redirects to the login page. The token got expire.

```
const settings: any = await response.json();
settings.automaticSilentRenew = true;
settings.includeIdTokenInSilentRenew = true;
settings.accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime = 30; // default 60
settings.checkSessionInterval = 5000; // default 2000;
settings.silentRequestTimeout = 20000;// default: 10000
settings.monitorSession = true;
settings.loadUserInfo = true;
settings.filterProtocolClaims = true;
settings.max_age = 10;
settings.prompt="login"
this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);


public async completeSignIn(url: string): Promise<IAuthenticationResult> {
    try {
      
      await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();

      const user = await this.userManager.signinCallback(url);
      
      this.userSubject.next(user);
      return this.success(user && user.state);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('There was an error signing in: ', error);
      return this.error('There was an error signing in.');
    }
  }
```

While doing some search I found that `prompt="login"` should work, but not able to solve it. How can I achieve if the application is active the silent token reniew should work if they close the browser or tab prompt the login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_age=10` is saying "if the user interactively signed in more than 10 seconds ago then force interactive authentication". In short I don't think you want that as it effectively disables silent renewal and will cause the authorize endpoint to return `error=login_required` if `prompt=none` is specified (which it will be for silent renewal).

Using `sessionStorage` to store UserManager state should acheive what you want as this is tied to the browser window and will be automatically cleared up if the window/tab is closed or the browser closed.

This will not affect the user's session cookie on the IDP however so you'd still want to manually specify `max_age=n` or `prompt=login` when you are doing the interactive sign in (i.e. if no local client-side session currently exists). To do this you can pass additional params to signinRedirect rather than defining them at UserManager settings level:

```
await manager.signinRedirect({ prompt: "login" });
```

Additionally, since these params can be tampered with it's wise to also check the `auth_time` claim in your backend to ensure the user really did authenticate recently.

Answer (score 0):

for this issue

> On browser or tab close I need to redirect the user back to the login
> page

you must switch from sessionStorage to localStorage,

```
new Oidc.UserManager({ userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }) }).signinRedirectCallback().then(function () {
window.location.replace("./");});
```

please check this [Page](https://bleepcoder.com/oidc-client-js/184694845/how-to-change-from-sessionstorage-to-localstorage-on)

For silent token refresh please check this [Page](https://code-maze.com/oauth2-refresh-token-angular-identityserver4/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting only prompt and removing the max_age also solve the issue for me

```
settings.prompt="login"
```